# vscode Editable Virtual Documents in Extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to use vscode to write an extension which interacts with my backend service.
The problem I am having is that my "documents" that I want to edit are actually nested JSON documents. The top level document I am managing looks something like this for instance:

```
{
 'filename': 'My JSON info.exp',
 'filecontent': '{"this": "that"}'
}
```

I'd like to open and edit these files in vscode.
Using Virtual Documents I got to the point where I could open a document from a custom tree, and display the filecontent in a document named with the filename. Worked perfectly until I tried to edit the document content.

I'd like to provide an editor for just the filecontent, then handle things like saves myself using my API.

I looked into the FileSystem Provider, but it doesn't look like what I am looking for as the uris have to actually exist... I think?

Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to do something similar with [Joplin](https://joplinapp.org/api/references/rest_api/) - opening, editing and saving notes via a REST API.

I'm not as far along as you, but it was my understanding from scanning through the docs that Virtual Documents were read-only. Because of that, I'm dropping my content into a TextDocument so it can be edited; I am super curious if there's a way to override a document's onSave() to do what we're both after.

Below is what I'm doing to open the text document; if you could share any insights into your progress (or better yet code) that'd be awesome.

```
  async openNote(item: Omit<FolderOrNote, 'item'> & { item: JoplinListNote }) {
    console.log('openNote: ', item.id, await 
      noteApi.get(item.id, [
        'id',
        'parent_id',
        'title',
        'is_todo',
        'todo_completed',
        'body'
      ]).then (
          note => {
            vscode.workspace.openTextDocument( {
              content: note.body,
              language: 'markdown'
            } ).then(
                doc => vscode.window.showTextDocument( doc )
            );
          }
        )
      )
  }
```

---

**Edit:**

Digging around some more it looks like maybe a [CustomEditor](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors) is needed.  A CustomEditor requires the extension to implement things like loading and saving into the model because VS Code is unaware of how to deal with the raw data.  There is also a CustomTextEditor but that appears to be tied to the local filesystem.

There's a YouTube video here that talks about it in detail:
https://youtu.be/Dekn2MHy9Os?t=1147

Here's the sample code:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/custom-editor-sample

Comment: What I ended up doing was just saving the file content locally. Then in my extension tree I added a "Commit' command that would update the item on the server. This allowed me to get kind of a "git" like interface. I could even then use the built in diff commands to alow the user to diff their local uncommitted version against the version on the server using a combination of virtual docs and locally saved docs.